# how to display bottom navbar without scrolling down

Tags: flutter

In my flutter code, I have created a separate navbar widget and called it on my page. I have used a single-child scroll view. now I have to scroll the page to see the navbar. I want it to be appeared bottom top of the page. how can I do this? the image shows when I scroll down how the nav bar appears. appreciate your help on this.

```
class ProfessionalProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfessionalProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfessionalProfile> createState() => _ProfessionalProfileState();
}

class _ProfessionalProfileState extends State<ProfessionalProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      drawer: HiddenDrawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new ExactAssetImage(
                          'assets/images/user.png'
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new Text(
                  'Nirosha Kumuduni',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new Text(
                  'neo@gmail.com',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/briefcase.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Profession',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width:200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: MainGreen.withOpacity(.3),
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      '   Interior Designer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )

              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/home.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Address',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width:200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: MainGreen.withOpacity(.3),
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      '   25/A, Horton Place, Colombo',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )

              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/phone-call.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Mobile Number',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width:180,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: MainGreen.withOpacity(.3),
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      '   +94 771122334',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )

              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/mail.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Email Address',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width:180,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: MainGreen.withOpacity(.3),
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      '   neo@gmail.com',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )

              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/hand-shake.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Business Name',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width:170,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: MainGreen.withOpacity(.3),
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      '   NEO GROUP',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/target.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Business Description',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width:320,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: MainGreen.withOpacity(.3),
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      '   25/A, Horton Place, Colombo',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Ratings & Reviews',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                new Text(
                  '4.1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/rating.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Center(
              child:   GestureDetector(
                child: MainButton("Edit Profile"),
                // onTap: () async {
                //   FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                //   if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                //     _formKey.currentState!.save();
                //     await LoginData();
                //     // Get.to(BottomNavigation());
                //   }
                // },
                onTap: (){
                  Get.to(DashboardScreen());
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height : 56,
                child: BottomNavigation()
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

//bottom navigation

```
class BottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigation> createState() => _BottomNavigationState();
}

class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;


  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Business',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                label: 'Reviews',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        ],
      ),


    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
class _ProfessionalProfileState extends State<ProfessionalProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation() , // your BottomNavigation here
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      drawer: HiddenDrawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [ ....
```

Comment: I try this. now the screen is empty with bottom navbar. I have re-uploaded my bottom navbar code to the question. can you refer and give me a suggestion what to do.

Comment: actually thank you I have wrap it from a container. now working